# How to modify JBoss classload to use different versions of third party library jars (parent last)

Tags: web-applications, jboss, classloader

I'm trying to figure out how to set up JBoss 5.1.0 so that the classloader is parent last, which I have done before with WebSphere. Basically we have several war files that need to use Spring 3. We have put the spring jars in the JBoss lib, so that we don't have to have spring jars inside each and every war file. However, one of the web apps needs to use Spring 2 (not our code). What I want to have happen is that specific war file will have the Spring 2 jars in its web-inf/lib folder, and use those Spring jars. All the other web apps will use the Spring 3 jars in the JBoss lib folder.

However, I am at a loss as to how to do this. I believe I should just have to put an xml file in the one war that needs to not read the jboss spring jars, but I can't quite get it right. I can't tell if I should be setting an isolation level for that war or what.

Or if there is a better solution than what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, it's 5.1.0. I'll update the question, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to set `java2ParentDelegation` to `false`. See this article for more details:

Reference: http://www.openscope.net/2010/07/15/setting-up-a-jboss-instance-v5-x-class-loading/